# Bad Access on storing NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, exc-bad-access, nsnumber

I'm using the following code to save a number in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]retain];
NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:indexPath.row];
[prefs setValue:num forKey:@"randomkeyhere"];
```

Only at some points I get a

> EXC_BAD_ACESS (code=2).

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this undefined behavior or something of that sort? I'm wondering why I only get it sometimes and not always.

Comment: so crazy , you retainning a Singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults` is a singleton object managed by iOS. It is not a new object that you initiate. Get rid of the `retain`.

Also, try setting a breakpoint in the method to see exactly where the program is crashing. Post the error's from the console below:

Comment: Did that, same thing happening. And thanks for the feedback, I'm new to iOS programming. Do you have any idea why this is only happening from time to time though?

Comment: never mind, I was able to debug it, it was an error somewhere else.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

in the singleton , the retain is like this

```
- (id)retain
{
    return self;
}
```

so , the retainCount will not add 1.

you can look at this :

### [singleton in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143162/singleton-in-objective-c)