# Use Singleton in Interface Builder with Swift

Tags: swift, interface-builder

In Objective-C, this worked well for a [Singleton in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609609/use-singleton-in-interface-builder)

```
static Universe *instance;

+ (Universe *)instance {
    return instance;
}

+ (id)hiddenAlloc {
    return [super alloc];
}

+ (id)alloc {
    return [self instance];
}

+ (void)initialize {
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = YES;
        instance = [[Universe hiddenAlloc] init];
    }
}
```

and due to the overwriting of the alloc, IB would pick up the only instance of `Universe`

Is this possible in Swift? [I've gotten stuck with my solution, which is [here on Github](https://github.com/drosenstark/SingletonInSwift).]

Comment: No because there is no such thing as `alloc` in Swift. You are munging fundamental memory management, and Swift won't let you do that. If this is important to you, why not write this part of the code in Objective-C?

Comment: @matt Thanks for that, agreed. I'm trying to imagine a hybrid where the singleton-ness is in Objective-C and then the `Universe` is a Swift subclass. Seems to me like that's impossible since the `initialize` must be tied to the specific class, right?

Comment: No, `initialize` can be called for subclasses. That's why a good `initialize` always checks what class this actually is.

Comment: This could be fun, I'll see what I come up with, thank you!

Comment: Hi @matt I posted an answer below. It's close to working, but it's somehow losing `IBOutlet` variables (though its hash value and memory address remain fixed). Any suggestions, hints, guidance (or discouragement, if that's what's necessary) would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @matt I posted a clean test project to Github at https://github.com/drosenstark/SingletonInSwift to make it very easy if one wanted to take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a start (I think). Superclass in Objective-C.

Please check it out on [Github](https://github.com/drosenstark/SingletonInSwift)... any help appreciated!

**Singleton.h (must be in Bridging Header)**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject

+ (Singleton *)instance;

@end
```

**Singleton.m**

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

static Singleton *instance;

+ (Singleton *)instance {
    return instance;
}

+ (id)hiddenAlloc {
    return [super alloc];
}

+ (id)alloc {
    return [self instance];
}

+ (void)initialize {
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = YES;
        instance = [[self hiddenAlloc] init];
    }
}

@end
```

**Universe.swift**

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - convenience access
let universe = Universe.sharedInstance

@objc(Universe)
class Universe : Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Universe()

    override class func instance() -> Singleton {
        return sharedInstance
    }
}
```

The `Universe` object is always showing the same hash (and memory address), but it's not holding on to its `IBOutlet` variables... so this is still 100% broken, but it's a start (probably).

Comment: It's pretty odd. The `initialize` is getting called exactly twice (once for `Universe`) and everything else seems so correct! Not sure what's up with my `IBOutlets`... anyway

Comment: If you really want a 'singleton' then you should have a private init method so that nothing else can create your singleton instance.  You should also make the class as final.

Comment: Thanks @Gargoyle i will do that as soon as I have the thing working.

Comment: It's easier to play with now, adding GitHub link

Comment: As you can see here -- https://github.com/drosenstark/SingletonInSwift -- the issue is that each time the `init` is called, while it does provide the same object, all the properties get set to their initial assignment (and `willSet` etc. is not run during the init)